# Django admin error

Tags: python, django, django-admin

while modifying [django-userena](http://django-userena.org/) `settings.py` I encounter this error

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'guardian',
 'south',
 'userena',
 'userena.contrib.umessages',
 'demo_project.profiles']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'userena.middleware.UserenaLocaleMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  214.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  196.                 return self.login(request)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
  331.         return login(request, **defaults)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in login
  59.     current_site = get_current_site(request)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in get_current_site
  92.         current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in get_current
  25.             current_site = self.get(pk=sid)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  349.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /admin/
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.
```

do you know what is causing this error?

**Edit**

Following **huck Harmston** instructions `Site.objects.get(pk=settings.SITE_ID)` returned this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 349, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.
>>> Site.objects.get(pk=settings.SITE_ID)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/elie/.django-projects/userena-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 349, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.
```

In my database there's a `site_id http://127.0.0.1:8000/' which is the domain name that i used instead of`example.com`

Comment: Do you have in your database a Site object with the id from your settings.py file?

Comment: Did you forget to run syncdb?

Comment: @burhan django-userena has 2 settings.py, one inside the `demo project` folder and one outside it, i did run syncdb inside the `demo project` folder, but i am editing the other settings.py file, there is no manage.py file to that, therefore i can't run syncdb

Comment: @StefanNch please read my edit

Answer (score 3):

Your `SITE_ID` setting's value likely does not correspond with the primary key of a `Site` object. You can verify by running this:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Python 2.7.1 [...]
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> Site.objects.get(pk=settings.SITE_ID)
<Site: example.com>
```

If the response of the final command is not a `Site` object (it'd likely raise a `Site.DoesNotExist` exception), then that's the problem. You can solve it by not setting `SITE_ID`, which is unnecessary if you are not using [django.contrib.sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/).

Answer (score -1):

I know this might sound weird, but I saw an error like this once. Try removing django.contrib.sites. It was colliding with another app that the person had installed.

Comment: It's not prudent to recommend that someone wholesale remove a dependency. They may not need the sites contrib package, but they might or one of their 3rd-party apps might need it. Besides, if a package conflicts with sites, that's a problem with that package, not sites. You shouldn't write anything that conflicts with Django's stuff, whether it's optional or not.